# Como posso transformar " em \" num script bash

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Eu fiz um pequeno script em Python que transformava um arquivo `.py` num bash script do Linux, porém, as aspas que estão dentro do arquivo Python acabam fazendo o script não funcionar. Tem algum modo de eu transformar todas as `"` de um texto em bash em `\"`?

O script que eu fiz é esse:

```
#!/bin/bash
pyprog=$(cat $1) # Salva nessa variável o texto do arquivo python

echo "#!/bin/bash
echo \"$pyprog\" | python" > $2

# A saída final desse programa seria algo parecido com:
# !bin bash
# echo "print "Exemplo de um programa em python"" | python
# Assim aspas do comando print vão interferir nas aspas do comando echo 

# Neste caso eu precisaria que o script automaticamente transformasse para
# echo "print \"Exemplo de um programa em python\"" | python
```

Comment: Use a barra invertida `\"` para livrar as `"` que não queira que o comando `echo` interprete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

escreva seu script da seguinte forma:

```
#!/bin/bash
pyprog=$(cat $1) # Salva nessa variável o texto do arquivo python

echo "#!/bin/bash
echo \"$(echo $pyprog | sed 's/"/\\"/g')\" | python" > $2
```

O comando `sed` vai fazer a mágica de substituir os caracteres `"` por `\"`.

No comando essa substituição está definda com `\\"` pois precisamos escapar a contra-barra para que o próprio bash não interprete as coisas da forma errada.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução usando o comando 'tr'

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
  echo "erro, precisa de 2 parametros"
  exit 1
fi

tr '"' '\' < $1 | python > $2
```